# In Python calculate GPA from score

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and I am currently taking a class that is teaching me the language. Right now, we just learned about conditional statements and my assignment is to write code that calculates a student's GPA based on three weighted categories (shown in the code). However, I can only print out the GPA based on certain percentages. A 4.0 is 94 and above, 3.5 is 89, 3.0 is 80, 2.5 is 75, 2.0 is 70, 1.5 is 65, 1.0 is 60, and anything below 60 is 0. My teacher said I have to use these numbers. I don't know how to calculate the GPA if the percentage does not meet these conditions. Can someone help and resolve the issue?

```
#Scores (made up point totals)
avgHwScore = float(input('What was your average homework score? (Out of 5)\n>>> '))
midTerm = float(input('What was your score on the mid-term? (Out of 30)\n>>> '))
finalExam = float(input('What was your score on the final exam? (Out of 50)\n>>> '))

#Converting to decimal
hwDec = avgHwScore/5
midDec = midTerm/30
finalDec = finalExam/50

#Weighted grades
hwWeighted = hwDec*.6
midWeighted = midDec*.2
finalWeighted = finalDec*.2
print('\nThe homework is weighted 60% and the mid-term and final exam are both weighted 20% each\n')
print('You earned ' + str(hwWeighted*100) + '% out of 60% in the homework category')
print('You earned ' + str(midWeighted*100) + '% out of 20% on mid-term category')
print('You earned ' + str(finalWeighted*100) + '% out of 20% on the final exam category\n')

#Final grade
finalGrade = (hwWeighted + midWeighted + finalWeighted)*100
if finalGrade >= 94:
    print('Your final grade is ' + str(finalGrade) + '%. You have a 4.0 in the class')
elif finalGrade == 89:
    print('Your final grade is ' + str(finalGrade) + '%. You have a 3.5 in the class')
elif finalGrade == 80:
    print('Your final grade is ' + str(finalGrade) + '%. You have a 3.0 in the class')
elif finalGrade == 75:
    print('Your final grade is ' + str(finalGrade) + '%. You have a 2.5 in the class')
elif finalGrade == 70:
    print('Your final grade is ' + str(finalGrade) + '%. You have a 2.0 in the class')
elif finalGrade == 65:
    print('Your final grade is ' + str(finalGrade) + '%. You have a 1.5 in the class')
elif finalGrade == 60:
    print('Your final grade is ' + str(finalGrade) + '%. You have a 1.0 in the class')
elif finalGrade < 60:
    print('Your final grade is ' + str(finalGrade) + '%. You have a 0.0 in the class')
```

Comment: You should typcially use [`numpy.average`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html) for calculating a weighted average. Example: `numpy.average([80, 90], weights=[4, 6])` gives 86.0

Answer (score 2):

For your code, and assuming that you can only have GPA's in multiples of 0.5, Python allows using conditionals within a range, by that I mean:

```
if finalGrade >= 94:
    print('Your final grade is ' + str(finalGrade) + '%. You have 4.0 GPA')
elif finalGrade >= 89:
    print('Your final grade is ' + str(finalGrade) + '%. You have 3.5 GPA')
```

Answer (score 0):

If using explicit conditionals, simply substitute `==` in your code with `>=`. I discourage you from using explicit conditionals, however, as it's a pretty naive way to write code, and it isn't really scalable.

#### Common setup:

The following setup is common to all techniques used below.

```
MAP = [(60, 1), (65, 1.5), (70, 2), (75, 2.5), (80, 3), (89, 3.5), (94, 4)]
BREAKPOINTS, GPAS = zip(*MAP)
```

The reason for using ascending order is that the `bisect` module seemingly requires it.

#### Linear search:

```
def scoretogpa_linear1(score):
    for index, breakpoint in enumerate(BREAKPOINTS):
        if score < breakpoint:
            return GPAS[index - 1] if index else 0
    return GPAS[index]
```

#### Linear search using `itertools`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

def scoretogpa_linear2(score):
    index = next(dropwhile(lambda indexed_breakpoint: score >= indexed_breakpoint[1], enumerate(BREAKPOINTS)), (len(BREAKPOINTS), None))[0]
    return GPAS[index - 1] if index else 0
```

#### Binary search:

This is motivated by the [score to grade](https://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html#other-examples) example found in the official Python docs.

```
from bisect import bisect_right

def scoretogpa_log(score):
    index = bisect_right(BREAKPOINTS, score)
    return GPAS[index - 1] if index else 0
```

#### Test:

```
SCORERS = scoretogpa_linear1, scoretogpa_linear2, scoretogpa_log

for breakpoint in BREAKPOINTS:
    for score in breakpoint - 1, breakpoint, breakpoint + 1:
        gpas = [scorer(score) for scorer in SCORERS]
        assert len(set(gpas)) == 1
        print(f'{score} {gpas[0]}')
```

Results:

```
59 0
60 1
61 1
64 1
65 1.5
66 1.5
69 1.5
70 2
71 2
74 2
75 2.5
76 2.5
79 2.5
80 3
81 3
88 3
89 3.5
90 3.5
93 3.5
94 4
95 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code, when changed with the suggestion Akumzui presented, will work correctly. However, using multiple if-else if blocks just makes the code unnecessarily long. Here is how you can shorten it by using a [dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm). This is safe to do only with Python 3.6 or newer, as the order of the keys in the dictionary is preserved.

```
grade_reference = {
  94: 4.0,
  89: 3.5,
  80: 3.0,
  75: 2.5,
  70: 2.0,
  65: 1.5,
  60: 1.0
}


finalGrade = 78
CGPA = 0.0
for item in grade_reference:
  if finalGrade >= item:
    CGPA = grade_reference[item]
    break
print(CGPA) #Prints 2.5
```

Dictionaries are not too far from your scope of learning right now, because it's a basic concept in Python. When the for loop begins, the variable `item` takes in the first left side value inside the dictionary, which is known as the key. If the grade you scored is higher than the key, then it prints the corresponding CGPA, which is known as the value. If not, it goes to the next key.